# Why does the residue theorem fail in the calculation of $\int _\gamma\frac{zdz}{1+z+z^4}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I tried to calculate

$$\int _\gamma\frac{z \, dz}{1+z+z^4}$$

where $\gamma$ is a finite rectangle made of lines that connect $\pm i2,\pm2$. There are 4 poles in this rectangle therefore the residue theorem states that the integral should be $i 8\pi$.

I noticed that if I substitute to

$w = \frac{1}{z}$

$ \int _\gamma \frac{dw}{w\sqrt{w^4+w^3+1}}$

I get one pole at $w = 0$. and then it equals $i 2 \pi$. So why do the two  solutions conflict?

Comment: Please show details of what you have done. What is the image of $\gamma$ under $z \to \frac 1 z$? And how do you know there are no poles inside $\gamma$?

Comment: You'll have four poles in the complex plane overall, so you must have missed three of them...

Comment: sorry you are right, there are 4 poles inside so it should be 8pi and not 2pi

Comment: therefore I cannot understand how $2 \pi i$ is the solution

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy added the substituted integral.

Comment: Do you compute the residues at the four poles and add?  I get $0$.

Comment: Well inside the $\sqrt{}$, the polynomials still have four zero points (in complex plane)? So there are more than one pole?

Comment: can someone try to solve this question from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the lowest absolute value for points on the rectangle is $\sqrt 2$, so the interior of the rectangle contains the disc of radius $\sqrt 2$ centered at the origin; but $(\sqrt 2)^4=4 > \sqrt 2 +1$ so all the roots of the equation $z^4+z+1=0$ are inside the rectangle.

Since $\gamma$ contains inside all the finite poles of $f(z)=1/(1+z+z^4)$, picking a large positive $R$ means that the integral on the domain bounded by $\gamma$ and the circle of radius $R$ is zero by Cauchy, hence $\int _\gamma\frac{zdz}{1+z+z^4}=\int _{|z|=R}\frac{zdz}{1+z+z^4}$

But $|\int _{|z|=R}\frac{zdz}{1+z+z^4}| \le 10/R^2$ for $R >100$ say since $|z^4+z+1|>\frac{|z|^4}{3}$ say and $|dz|=R d\theta$, so it goes to zero of we let $R \to \infty$, so our original integral is zero.

The result is true for any rational functions with residue at infinity zero, so in particular if it is $P/Q, \deg Q \ge \deg P +2$

Comment: attention, you have chosen |z|=R while the question is about a  rectangle. might it be that some poles aren't in the rectangle?

Comment: you are right - I was misled by your statement that the 4 poles are in the rectangle and didn;t look at its bounds carefully, so my apologies - will think of this more carefully

Comment: actually, all the roots of the equation are indeed inside the rectangle so the integral is zero as noted

Comment: hmmm can you explain why the other method fails then? why the variable substitution leads me to the wrong answer? as the only pole I get is at w=0?

Comment: not sure you do substitution right as under $z \to 1/w, dz =-dw/w^2$ the integral becomes the integral of $w/(w^4-w^3+1)$ though one has to be careful since $1/z$ is not a reparametrization of $\gamma$ hence there is no guarantees the integrals are actually equal

Comment: can you explain why taking R to infinity is legit? As the original bound was not a circle with infinite radius?

Comment: Cauchy theorem says that if $f$ is analytic on a domain bounded by two (rectifiable) curves the integral of $f$ is the same on the two curves; taking the domain bounded by $\gamma$ and a circle of radius $R$ large gives the equality of the integrals $I_{\gamma}=I_R$ and then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $R$ st $|I_R| \le \epsilon$ hence $|I_{\gamma}| \le \epsilon$ etc

Comment: do you mean Cauchy's integral theorem? does it require the function to be holomorphic?

Comment: if it's meromorphic you have some residues inside in general, so the integrals on the two curbes (inner and uter) differe by those, but if the function is holomoprhic, so no residue, the integrals are equal

Comment: but this function is meromorphic  isn't it? @Conrad

Comment: on the domain bounded by $\gamma$ and $|z|=R$ large it is analytic since all the poles are inside the inner domain of $\gamma$

Comment: if a function is holomorphic, doesn't it mean that it does not have any poles?

Comment: yes precisely and $f$ has no poles on the domain $D$ bounded by $\gamma$ and $|z|=R$

Comment: what? what about all the places that $1+z+z^4=0$?

Comment: those are inside $\gamma$ so not in $D$ (remember $D$ is the part of the outside of $\gamma$ inside $|z| \le R$ so in other words $z=x+iy, |x|+|y| \ge 2, x^2+y^2 \le R^2, R \ge 100$ say

Comment: ohh you are looking the domain of a circle r minus the rectangle? what happen if I'll try to apply to the residue theorem inside the rectangle?

Comment: you get zero of course so the integral on the outer curve is equal to the integral on the inner curve

Comment: so it doesn't matter if I'll take the outer domain or the inner domain as long all the poles will be at one of the domains and not the other? is there a name for this result?

Comment: not sure what you ask - the integral here happens to be zero because the function decays fast at infinity, so the integral on the big circle goes to zero; however if you had something like $\frac{z^3}{z^4+z+1}$ the integral on the big circle would converge to $2\pi i$ so the integral on $\gamma$ would be that -  if all the poles are inside $\gamma$ you can move freely to closed curves outside; if all the poles were outside, you would change the integral any time you pass one (or you can freely move the path inside $\gamma$ and then the integral wuld be zero since you coud shrink it to a point)

Comment: (comment continued as it got too long) - this is the standard method of computing integrals with residues, by switching paths and taking into account the poles inside the figure made with the original and changed paths; start with a closed curve, you switch to another closed curve and change anytime you pass a pole in-between; if no poles then no change